# Как получить число в котором пробелом отделены группы разрядов?

Tags: python, парсер

Извлекаю с сайта цены. Они поданы с пробелом в формате `1 558.5854 USDT)` Каким образом я могу получить `1558.5854`?

Answer (score 0):

Вот функция которая найдет все числа в строке, и возвратит список с числами. Там уже под себя можете дописать (разделено пробелом, точкой и тд.):

```
def getNumber(s):
    constants = []
    l = len(s)
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        s_int = ''
        a = s[i]
        while '0' <= a <= '9' or a == '-' or a == '.':
            if a == '-':
                s_int = a + s_int
            else:
                s_int += a
            i += 1
            if i < l:
                a = s[i]
            else:
                break
            if a == '-':
                i -= 1
                break
        i += 1
        if s_int != '':
            constants.append(float(s_int))
    return constants
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "1 558.5854 USDT"
y = ''.join(i for i in x if not i.isalpha())

print(y.replace(" ", ""))
```

Можете это в функцию обернуть и будет более удобно. Если входящих данных много, то соответственно в цикл.

Решение далеко не лучшее точно, но всё же.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Col1': ['1 558.5854 USDT', '1 435.9087 EURT'],
        'Col2': ['One', 'Two']
    }
)

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: float(''.join(a for a in x if a.isnumeric() or a == '.')))
```